# Accessing a container child widget dimensions in a constructor

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm

Let's say I have a class with two `Gtk::Containers` like so:

```
class Example : public Gtk::VBox
{
public:
    Example();
    virtual ~Example();

private:
    Gtk::HBox m_c1; // First container
    Gtk::Grid m_c2; // Second container
};
```

Constructing an `Example` is implemented this way:

```
Example::Example()
{
    const int nbRows{6};
    const int nbColumns{7};

    for(int col{0}; col < nbColumns; ++col)
    {
        Gtk::Button* btn {new Gtk::Button("A")};

        m_c1.pack_start(*btn);
    }

    for(int row{0}; row < nbRows; ++row)
    {
        for(int col{0}; col < nbColumns; ++col)
        {
            Gtk::Button* btn {new Gtk::Button("A")};

            m_c2.attach(*btn, col, row, 1, 1);
        }
    }

    // Layout setup:
    pack_start(m_c1);
    pack_start(m_c2);

    show_all();
}
```

What I want to do is to make sure the child widgets in `m_c2` are the same size as the child widget in `m_c1`, to ensure visual consistency between the two containers. Otherwise, it looks like this:

[image: Inconsistent sizes]

Just to make sure, I do not want `m_c1` to be made a `Gtk::Grid`.

Here's what I have tried so far: I used the `get_child_at()` method available from the `Gtk::HBox` `m_c1` to get a reference to its first child. I then called `get_width()` and `get_height()` on that child. The idea was to feed `m_c2`'s child widgets these dimensions. The problem is that the returned reference is a `nullptr`.

From some posts I have read, it seems my widgets may no yet be realized, and that would explain my difficulties. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set each button in the grid to [expand horizontally](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-set-hexpand). Then all the sizing will take care of itself.